# node js. how do i call local file from html

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

i have this file to run app.js

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var path = __dirname + '/views/';


router.get("/",function(req,res){
 res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});

app.use("/",router);

app.use("*",function(req,res){
 res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});

app.listen(8080,function(){
 console.log("Live at Port 8080");
});
```

and i have "index.html" inside of "views" folder.
i want to import my local css file inside of "css" folder.
i tried to call the file like this

```
<link href="css/main.css">
```

or

```
<link href="../css/main.css">
```

but it didnt work.
is there any specific method to get them?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you don't seem to have set a folder for static files. Ex:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));`

After you make one it should start looking for the css in there. For example 
`static/css/main.css` can be used with `<link href="css/main.css">`

Comment: i solve the problem but i have to put rel="stylesheet" inside the link. thank for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use express's serving static files, as explained in their API : https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0):

Put your css folder inside view folder

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var path = __dirname + '/views/';
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));


router.get("/",function(req,res){
 res.sendFile("index.html");
});

app.use("/",router);

app.use("*",function(req,res){
 res.sendFile("index.html");
});

app.listen(8080,function(){
 console.log("Live at Port 8080");
});
```